# Match digits (which may contain spaces) except when preceded by a specific word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this regular expression to look for numbers in a text that do not belong to a price (in euro):

```
(?<!EUR )(\d\s*)+
```

I want it to not match:

```
EUR 10 000
```

And I want it to match the numbers in the following cases:

```
{3}  
10 000  
347835
```

The problem I now face is that it matches the numbers I want it to fine, but it does also matches the `0 000` part of the text that I don't want it to match.

**Edit:**
I want to match all numbers (including spaces in between numbers) unless they are preceded by "EUR ".
To make it more clear what I want to match I will provide all the cases from above and make the things I **want to match** bold:

EUR 10 000
{**3**}
**10 000**
**347835**

What my regular expression **currently** matches is:
EUR 1**0 000**
{**3**}
**10 000**
**347835**

Comment: @anubhava I want to match the 3 but not the curly brackets. My regex flavor is java.

Comment: Then you can try: `^(?!.*\bEUR )\D*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using a capture group, you can match what you don't want and capture what you want to keep.

```
\bEUR *\d+(?:[ \d]*\d)?\b|\b(\d+(?: +\d+)*)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bEUR *` Match EUR and optional spaces
- `\d+(?:[ \d]*\d)?\b` Match 1+ digits and optional spaces and digits ending on a digit followed by a word boundary
- `|` Or
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1** (The value that you are interested in)

  - `\d+(?: +\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat 1+ spaces and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6oM55/1)

Note that you can also use `\s` instead of a space, but that can also match newlines.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I wasn't clear enough in my specification - your regular expression also matches "EUR 10 000" which I do not want to match. I edited my original question to make it more clear what I need.

Comment: @0plusKminus the actual result you want is in the capture group.

Comment: @Silviu Burcea But it is not the capture group I want. 
I found a solution that works for me using The fourth bird's solution by making the first part of the OR a capture group. Because I actually want to keep prices as is and delete all other numbers. Sorry, that should probably have been in the original question.